# Can we predict harmonic generation from Maxwell's equations?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, computational-physics, maxwell-equations, non-linear-optics

One typical experimental setup to generate harmonics from a laser pulse is to irradiate some plasma stab with a laser, register both reflected and transmitted waves, and the spectrum of those waves should have more harmonics than the spectrum of the incident wave. Since the EM wave behaves according to Maxwell's equations, one of their solutions should predict this behavior.

For this goal, and from a computational point of view, one common procedure is to model the plasma stab as a set of moving charges whose dynamics will create some EM field, let's call them $\vec{E}_P$ and $\vec{B}_P$ (plasma E and plasma B). On the other hand, the laser pulse is just an EM wave, $\vec{E}_L$ and $\vec{B}_L$ that propagates "freely" through the system. At the end, we would output the sum $\vec{E}_L + \vec{E}_P$, whose spectrum should have more harmonics than $\vec{E}_L$. However, in no way I am getting this result.

The problem has to be with the use of Ampere's Law,
$$\nabla\times\vec{B}_P(x,t) = \mu_0\vec{J}_P(x,t) + \mu_0\epsilon_0\:\partial_t\vec{E}_P(x,t)$$
and Gauss' Law:
$$\nabla\cdot\vec{E}_P(x,t) = \rho(x,t)/\epsilon_0$$

Out of the plasma stab both $\vec{J}_P$ and $\rho(x,t)$ are by definition $0$, and therefore there will be no fields. Computationally, this will recover the incident field, i.e, $\vec{E}_L + \vec{E}_P = \vec{E}_L, \forall x$out of the plasma stab. How can we then predict harmonic generation from Maxwell equations?

Comment: @AndrewSteane Edited ;)

Comment: [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1140/epjst/e2011-01503-3)

this covers different ways of propagating EM fields, also interaction with nonlinear media, iirc, also in Max eqs framework.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick and therefore brief reply; hope it helps but others may be more helpful. For harmonic generation you require a non-linear response of the medium to the driving fields. And once you have a non-linear response, harmonic generation is almost guaranteed. The details are to do with efficiency. It is more efficient when all parts of the harmonic response you want are in phase (i.e. they contribute with a phase matching that of a single wave). This is called 'phase matching' as I expect you know; it can also be understood via momentum conservation.

Your question concerns Maxwell Equs and you assert that in the region of space where charge density and current are zero, you will get $E_P=0$ and $B_P=0$. But it does not follow. When $\rho=0$ and ${\bf j}=0$ you can have wavelike solutions (all the free space solutions) so in this example you can have $E_P \ne 0$ and $B_P \ne 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Maybe I should have written it - what if the limits of the plasma stab are grounded to $\Phi = 0V$? Then is when I guess the radiation is "killed"